# ColorAnimation to animate the listviewItem color on Swipe - WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, listviewitem, coloranimation

I'm trying to change the color of the listview item on swipe right using the following story board, but it throws an exception which says

> WinRT information: ColorAnimation cannot be used to animate property Background due to incompatible type.
>   Additional information: No installed components were detected.

This the code I've used. This is written in the manipulationDelta event

```
Grid ChannelGrid = (Grid)sender;
Grid DeleteGrid = (Grid)((Grid)(ChannelGrid.Parent)).Children[1];
```

The grids are the item template for the listviewitem and to which the manipulation events are wired.

```
else if (e.Position.X - initialpoint.X > 30 && ChannelGrid.Width == 380) // Swipe right
        {
            e.Complete();
            Storyboard SwipeRight = new Storyboard();

            ColorAnimation changeColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
            changeColorAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            changeColorAnimation.To = Colors.Green;
            changeColorAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(changeColorAnimation, ChannelGrid);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(changeColorAnimation, "Background");//**WRONG**
            SwipeRight.Children.Add(changeColorAnimation);
            SwipeRight.Begin();
         }
```

Comment: you can answer your own question in the answer box, and then mark as answered

Comment: @thumbmunkeys yep. Did that.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :D It is the TargetProperty which causes the exception. You need to set the target property as following

```
PropertyPath p = new PropertyPath("(ChannelGrid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(changeColorAnimation, p.Path);
```

and not

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(changeColorAnimation, "Background");//**WRONG**
```